# Get current script's and its parent folder path

Tags: php, development, joomla-api

Is there any Joomla way to return the path or parent's folder path of a current script?

So far when needed, I am using the Joomla Constants and building manually the remaining of the path. It's also possible with php, but I am wondering if there is any Joomla API functionality to get around this.

So let's say I am inside a template override:

```
templates/mytemplate/html/my_component/my_view/template.php
```

And want to create a new directory inside the parent "view" directory in order to place a file inside it, like so:

```
templates/mytemplate/html/my_component/my_view/newDir/newfile.ext
```

Then I want to call/link that new newFile.ext from the template.php file.

Is there any Joomla way to get the path of my_view dir?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question with more details, your question is broad to understand..

Comment: @Nagarjun:: sure - I added a simple example.

Comment: I am not sure Joomla way, but you could simply use `dirname ( __FILE__ )`

Comment: And to get parent of current directory `dirname( dirname(__FILE__) );`

Comment: Dirname is always an option. But wondering if there is any Joomla API functionality. Think there is something similar in WP.

Comment: I'm trying to understand why you would need this, when the `dirname ( __FILE__ )` option from php is available. It reminds me of some old Joomla workarounds that are no longer used because of new functionality available in php 5.x. DRY I say...

Comment: Do you wish to find out the path for file referencing purposes (e,g, from within PHP) or for URI-building purposes?  Your example quotes a file ending in .ext which you may simply have used as an example, but there is an implication that you might want to build an URI to supply in the generated HTML

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no Joomla API to get the current directory. There is no reason for it since `dirname(__FILE__)` works perfectly fine :-)

If you need to sanitise the filename, you can use  [`JPath::clean()`](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/JPath.html#method_clean).